# .Net HttpClient.GetStreamAsync() behaves differently to .GetAsync()

Tags: .net, httpclient

I've been trying to solve an issue I've encountered when downloading a batch of images in my app.

If I use `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(url)` to download the batch, then it seems like some of the requests will timeout, and eventually error.

However if I use `HttpClient.GetAsync(url)`, then the entire batch will download without any issue.

My suspicion is that it has something to do with ports not being freed up when invoking `.GetStreamAsync(url)`, however I could be talking nonsense.

Below is a code snippet that demonstrates the issue.

```cs
async Task Main()
{   
    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
    var imageUrl = "https://tenlives.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Found-Kitten-0-8-Weeks-Busy-scaled.jpg";
    var downloadTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 15)
                                .Select(async u =>
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        //Option 1) - this will fail
                                        var stream = await httpclient.GetStreamAsync(imageUrl);
                                        //End Option 1)

                                        //Option 2) - this will succeed
                                        //var response = await httpclient.GetAsync(imageUrl);
                                        //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                                        //var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                                        //End Option 2)

                                        return stream;
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine($"Error downloading image");
                                        throw;
                                    }
                                }).ToList();
    

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {       
        Console.WriteLine("================ Failed to download one or more image " + e.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Successful downloads: {downloadTasks.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).Count()}");
}
```

In the code block of the linq `Select` statement, `Option 1)` will fail as described above. If you  comment out 1), and uncomment Option 2), then everything will succeed.

Can anybody explain what might be happening here?

EDIT: This seems to work ok with .net core. I can reproduce this issue using .net framework 4.7.2 and below

EDIT2: I've also observed that if I increase the default connection limit by adding
`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 30;`
then the error no longer happens, however this does not explain why it fails for Option 1) but succeeds for Option 2)

Comment: Weird. I tested, the two options work on my computer.

Comment: No! Don't tell me that! That makes this even harder :( I have been able to reproduce this on multiple machines

Comment: I've just added that it seems to work ok with .net core. But fails with .net framework.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only difference between `GetStreamAsync` and `GetAsync` + `ReadAsStreamAsync` is that `GetStreamAsync` uses `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @RichardDeeming, `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync` call `HttpClient.GetAsync` with `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.

The code can be rewritten as follows:

```cs
async Task Main()
{   
    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
    var imageUrl = "https://tenlives.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Found-Kitten-0-8-Weeks-Busy-scaled.jpg";
    var downloadTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 15)
        .Select(async u =>
        {
            try
            {
                //Option 1) - this will fail
                var response = await httpclient.GetAsync(imageUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                //End Option 1)

                //Option 2) - this will succeed
                //var response = await httpclient.GetAsync(imageUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
                //End Option 2)

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                return stream;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error downloading image");
                throw;
            }
        }).ToList();

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {       
        Console.WriteLine("================ Failed to download one or more image " + e.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Successful downloads: {downloadTasks.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).Count()}");
}
```

Next `HttpClient.GetAsync` call `HttpClient.SendAsync`. We can see the method's code on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L365) :

```cs
//I removed the uninterested code for the question
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
    client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;
        if(completionOption == HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(response);
        }
        else
        {
            response.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync(int.MaxValue).ContinueWith(contentTask =>
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(response);
            });
        }
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

With `HttpClient.GetAsync` (or `SendAsync(HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead)`), the received content in a network buffer is read and integrated in a local buffer.

I'm not sure about the network buffer, but I think a buffer somewhere (network card, OS, HttpClient, ???) is full and blocks new responses.

You can correct the code by correctly managing this buffer, for example by disposing the associated streams :

```cs
var downloadTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 15)
.Select(async u =>
{
    try
    {
        var stream = await httpclient.GetStreamAsync(imageUrl);
        stream.Dispose(); //Free buffer
        return stream;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error downloading image");
        throw;
    }
}).ToList();
```

In .Net Core, the original code work without correction.
The [HttpClient class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2b3f76c8e3ccb28aefbf5ca879a7cf5933b2642a/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L509) has been rewrited and certainly improved.

Comment: Thanks very much for a great explanation.